# Can we extend time-based retention at blob level in Azure blob storage if yes do we have rest API's/API for the same

Tags: containers, blob, azure-blob-storage, retention

Can we extend time-based retention at blob level in Azure blob storage? If yes, do we have rest API's/API for the same?

Currently I see time-based retention I can apply at container level.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not support now.

As you have pointed, users can **configure time-based retention policies and legal hold tags at the container level**. By using simple container-level settings, users can create and lock time-based retention policies, extend retention intervals, set and clear legal holds, and more. These **policies apply to all the blobs in the container**, both existing and new.

If you still want have this feature, you can give your [voice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage) to give your feedback.

Comment: Thank you so much ..and do we have restapi's/api for extending at container level.

Comment: You can refer to this article to [Create  Immutability Policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/blobcontainers/createorupdateimmutabilitypolicy). And the property `properties.allowProtectedAppendWrites` can only be changed for unlocked `time-based` retention policies.

Comment: If it helps you, please accept it as answer. Click checkbox to turn it green.